# Como procesar un array file creada con javascript en php

Tags: php

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda. Tengo un **input file** el cual recorro con un ciclo for mediante javascript y agrego cada file a un array para ser enviada a PHP mediante un form data y Ajax, pero cuando quiero ver el array en php solo devuelve [Object File]

```
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append('imagenesDescripcion',imagenesDescripcion);
const imagenesDescripcion = new Array();
let imagenes = document.querySelector('input[name="files"]');       
        if(imagenes.files){
            let file = imagenes.files;
            for(let i = 0;i < file.length;i++){
                let nombre = file[i].name
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);
                reader.onload = function() {
                    let image = new Image();
                    image.src = reader.result;
                    image.onload = function(){
                        imagenesDescripcion.push(file[i])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
$.ajax({  
            url:"<?php echo $dominioRaiz;?>logica/admin/web/agregar_producto.php",
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            method: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:false,
            data: datos,    
            processData:false,  
            success:function(data){             
                console.log(data.html1)
            }
        });
```

Y en php

```
$tmp = $_POST['imagenesDescripcion'];

        return $tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Me extraña que el código funcione, porque primero tratas de acceder a una constante que defines justo en la siguiente línea

```
datos.append('imagenesDescripcion',imagenesDescripcion);
const imagenesDescripcion = new Array();
```

Luego, la función `reader.onload()` se ejecuta hasta que la imagen se cargó y, por tanto, lo más seguro es que la petición AJAX se haya enviado mucho antes de que se terminen de agregar las imágenes al arreglo.

Ya que estás usando [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), aprovecha las opciones que te da para [agregar elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) y agrega corchetes en el nombre, para que sea un arreglo:

```
// Crea el objeto
let datos = new FormData();
let imagenes = document.querySelector('input[name="files"]');

// Si solo se envían archivos, valida que al menos se agregó uno
if(imagenes.files.length == 0) {
    return;
}

// Recorrer archivos
for(let i = 0; < imagenes.files.length; i++) {
    // Agregar archivo con corchetes en el nombre de campo
    datos.append('imagenesDescripcion[]', imagenes.files[i]);
}
```

Después de esto ya puedes procesar la petición AJAX y, en PHP, recibirás los archivos en `$_FILES['imagenesDescripcion']`